# How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-formula

How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using Lotus Notes Fourmular

Answer (score 4):

If you are using lotusScript you can use either of these:

Returns the difference in seconds as a double

```
difference = notesdatetimeobj.TimeDifferenceDouble(othernotesdatetimeobj)
```

Returns the difference in seconds as a long

```
difference = notesdatetimeobj.TimeDifference(othernotesdatetimeobj)
```

If you are using @formulas you can just substract one date from the other and it will return the difference in seconds as well:

```
difference := date1 - date2;
```

Hope that helps.